# Firebase refresh id tokens for server authentication

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a project using firebase where I use firebase id token to verify user on back-end.
Actually, on client, when a user login I use `getIdToken(true)` and attach it to my requests header.
On server for each request I use `verifyIdToken` to check if the user is logged in and it's valid.

The problem is that after some time the token expire and the backend is not able to verify the user.

My question is: how to get this work?

I think about using a request interceptor from client side to get an id token for each request but i don't know if this is a good practice and if I have to invalidate the other tokens too with `admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(userId)`.
Thanks in advance.

**client**

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    return config
  }
  return firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(token => {
    config.headers.Authentication = token
    return config
  })
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error)
})
```

**server**

```
let decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
let userId = decodedToken.uid;
```